# How to run Snes game on Mame via GUI with Mame recoqnizing different games as different machines?

Tags: mame

I can run snes games on mame line.

I did that by just changing the name of the rom to something mame friendly. However, I can do so only with command line. Also Mame think that the game name is "snes" instead of Super Double Dragon.

I wonder if I should just merge snes rom and the double dragon.sfc inside one zip file. Is that the proper way to convert?

Mame .226 seems to be the only snes emulator that can scretch screen, make pixels more smooth, and have reasonable autofire feature allowing me to turn a button into autofire button. I want them all. Not higan. Not retroarch. Not as far as I know.

I have a rom called

The file name is Super Double Dragon (USA).zip and it contains only one file Super Double Dragon (USA).sfc

Just for research purpose, you can get a copy at https://wowroms.com/en/roms/super-nintendo/download-super-double-dragon-usa/29456.html but I am sure there are other legitimate ways to get them.

Now, I can try running Mame with run command. I can do

```
D:\Games\Mame>mame64 snes "Super Double Dragon (USA).zip"

"Super Double Dragon (USA).zip" approximately matches the following
supported software items (best match first):

* Software list "snes" (Nintendo SNES cartridges) matches:
sddragonu         Super Double Dragon (USA)
sddragon          Super Double Dragon (Euro)
sddragonp         Super Double Dragon (Euro, Prototype)
syakuman          Super Double Yakuman (Jpn)
```

It seems that with Mame you cannot use normal rom naming. So I did the reasonable thing. I change the zip file to sddragonu. Then I run

```
D:\Games\Mame>mame64 snes sddragonu
```

It works. I saw this screen

[image]

So far so good.

However, I cannot do this from GUI.

If I run Mame64 first, super double dragon is not one of the available ROM.

Here is in my rom directory

[image]

However, if I run mame first this is what I see

Well... I can't run mame64.exe in window so I can't use snip to get screenshot. Basically I see SNES as one available ROM and I do not see super double dragon at all.

After I see that screen, I can press 1 to do 1 player start, however I can't press anything anymore.

No key works. I cannot control my character at all

Not with keyboard not with my game pad

[image]

How to fix that? Am I doing something wrong?

Note I will try to play the game first with keyboard but I do not think it's the problem. I played final fight with my gamepad just fine.

Note. It turns out everything work.

[image]

It seems that I need to change key during actual game play or something.

So the biggest problem now is that I cannot select super double dragon without command line.

Okay the problem now is that Mame does not think that super double dragon is a different game than say super mario world.

Obviously, I want different .cfg for both. In super double dragon I want autofire in kick and punch but in different game I want autofire at different things.

Yet this is the cfg files in my ROM

It will be like neogeo.zip right? We can set different input for different games.

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I read that somewhere that I forget that the ROM need to be put on special directory

For snes

the roms need to be put on roms/snes

Then it works.

Where I read that I forget

Where is it documented I have no idea

This is a resources but I have no idea.

https://choccyhobnob.com/demystifying-mame-roms/

My main problem with mame rom, namely that I want different game in snes to have different config is still not solved. Mame think that all those different games are just different catridge of the same "machine" called SNES.

That means autofire setting in one game is used on another.

Everything else is fine. Mame runs those very well